# While making executable from python "ImportError: no module named _utils"

Tags: python, module, scikit-learn, executable, importerror

I am getting this error while making an exe from pyinstaller. Although I get so  many error while making exe but this one is difficult to avoid. 
In line 6 I get the above mentioned error. df3 is an object which contains 3(here n) DataFrames. I am running this loop for each DataFrame.

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.utils import check_array
from sklearn.tree.tree import DTYPE 
DF4=pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(n):
    DF=pd.DataFrame()
    DF=pd.DataFrame(df3[i])
    DF.columns=Name1
    DF[C]=y[b[i]]
    W=DF
    Y=DF[C]
    W=W.drop([C],axis=1)    
    Wtrain, Wtest, Ytrain, Ytest = train_test_split(W, Y,test_size=0.4)
    Wtest=pd.DataFrame(Wtest)
    clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion='gini',max_depth=2)
    clf.fit(Wtrain, Ytrain)
    clf.predict_proba(Wtest[:len(W)])
    #print W.head(2)
    A=check_array(W, dtype=DTYPE)
    #print A[5]
    def get_node(W):
        return clf.tree_.apply(check_array(W, dtype=DTYPE))

    node_idx, = get_node(Wtest[:1])
    Ytrain[get_node(Wtrain) == node_idx].mean()
    s=clf.predict_proba(Wtest[:len(W)])

    DF1=pd.DataFrame(s)
    DF1.columns=['score','score2']
    DF2=Wtest
    DF2['score']=list(10*DF1['score'].round(1))
    DF3=pd.concat([DF4,DF2],axis=0)
    DF4=DF3
    DF3.to_csv(workdir+"\\slide_output_result_"+runid+'.csv',index=False)
```

`

Comment: Might need more details for this error to locate the problem